# Assign variable by referencing another

Tags: variables, ansible

In the following Ansible Playbook, I am trying to create a user's password using predefined variables from `defaults/main.yml` which in return calls password from `vars/passwords.yml`. this file will be vaulted later.

## vars/passwords

```
---
passwords:
  foobar: 
     password: pass1234
```

## defaults/main.yml

```
users:
  - username: foobar
    group: barfoo
    password: "{{passwords.foobar}}"
```

## tasks/main.yml

```
- include_vars: passwords.yml

- name: Create user
  user:
    name: "{{item.username}}"
    group: "{{item.group}}"
    password: "{{item.password | password_hash('sha512') }}"
```

When I run this playbook, I get the following error:

```
ERROR:
{
    "msg": "[{u'username': u'foobar',
     u'group': u'barfoo',
     u'password': u'{{passwords.username}}'}]: 'list object' has no attribute 'username'"
}
```

Any idea how can I achieve assigning a variable by referencing another one.

Answer (score 1):

the first file you provided, has `passwords` as a list variable, while in your `defaults/main.yml` file you are expecting a dictionary variable (`passwords.foobar`).

please change 1st file contents to:

```
---
passwords:
  foobar: pass1234
```

cant comment about the rest, it looks to me that the `tasks/main.yml` is missing a line, probably a line including `with_items` statement. I dont imply its a problem in your code, you just probably didn't paste all your code to this question.

Comment: fixed my vars/passwords to reflect what I am looking for. I also  
 sharing a work around I come up with.

Answer (score 0):

With the current variables files (defaults and vars), the solution for me was to call the password for user bar using the username as a key. I currently have:

```
- include_vars: passwords.yml

- name: Create user
  user:
    name: "{{item.username}}"
    group: "{{item.group}}"
    password: "{{item.password | password_hash('sha512') }}"
```

the new `defaults/main.yml` will not have a password key/value:

```
users:
  - username: foobar
    group: barfoo
```

Now with `vars/passwords.yml` :

```
---
passwords:
  foobar: 
     password: pass1234
```

I can edit my change my task to:

```
- include_vars: passwords.yml

- name: Create user
  user:
    name: "{{item.username}}"
    group: "{{item.group}}"
    password: "{{passwords[item.username].password | password_hash('sha512') }}"
```

This solved my problem, and allows me to vault `passwords.yml`.
Please let me know if you have any improvements or suggestions.